# Problems with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

When I trying to get item index by below code.

```
Company company = getDefaultCompany();
companyArrayAdapter.getPosition(company);
```

I always to get result of -1. I don't understand what's wrong?
Because

```
companyArrayAdapter also have type Company.
private ArrayAdapter<Company> companyArrayAdapter;
```

Next you can see Company class declaration.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName=Company.TABLE_NAME)
public class Company {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "company";

    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull=false)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField
    private  String address;

    @DatabaseField
    private  String phone;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<Contract> contracts;

    public  Company(){

    }
}
```

Comment: where you have initialized array adapter? edit and post the code of  your arrayadapter

Comment: Array adapter returns -1 when there is no index found for that object. debug and check what is this method is returning `getDefaultCompany()`.

Comment: getDefaultCompany() has value.

Comment: ArrayAdapter initialization in onViewCreated event.

Comment: could you post your `getDefaultCompany()` code

Comment: You've not overridden `equals()` in `Company`, so unless the exact object that `getDefaultCompany()` returns has been added to the collection backing the `Adapter`, `getPosition()` will return `-1`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike.M. you're really helped me. 
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.id.equals(((Company)obj).getId());
    }

Comment: No problem. You might want to have a read through this, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java. Also, I think Android Studio has a code generation wizard somewhere that will help you properly create those methods. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` uses [List.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method which and it can't compare your custom `Company` class objects and always returns **"Not Found"** index (`-1`).

So you should override `getPosition()` method int your custom adapter which extends `ArrayAdapter`:

```
@Override
public int getPosition(@Nullable Company company) {
    /* here write logic of finding your company in companies list and retur index*/
     return index;
}
```

P.S
If you had snippet of your custom adapter I would give you more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the loop of the list

```
var list=adapter.your_list

var toMatch=yourObject

for((index,elem) in list.withIndex()){
if(elem.someUniqueProperty == toMatch.someUniqueProperty){
var needed_index=index
}
}
```